# How to install Twist into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, twist

I have installed Twist on Windows 7 32-bit by using "Twist-win32.win32.x86-13.1.0.13112-be932387dc00b6.exe". I want to install Twist into eclipse. I'm using Eclipse Indigo. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visiting the website of Thoughtworks gives you the instructions:

http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/docs/twist/13.1/help/how_do_i_install_twist_into_eclipse.html